# Windows Shutdown Script

Tags: script, shutdown

Don’t know if anyone can offer a bit of assistance with this.
I use a program called Folder Lock to prevent access to certain folders.  If the PC is shut down without first closing the program, the folders are unlocked the next time it restarts.

I am trying to use a script which will automatically close the Folder Lock program on shutdown.

I’m using Windows 10 and there is only one logon.

The script is located in the root of my D:\ drive for the moment although I have tried it in the Documents folder on the C:\ drive

The script is saved as a .bat file and I know it works because when I double click on it, the Folder Lock program closes and Windows shuts down.

The problem is getting the script to run when Windows is closed down using the shutdown button.  I think I’ve added it to the group policy correctly, but it doesn’t work.  I even put a 20 second time delay for shutdown in the script, but it just closes without any delay therefore, I’m don’t think Windows is even looking at the script.

[image: Group Policy Screenshot here]

[image: Script Screenshot here]
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, you would be telling Windows to shutdown twice with this script. Once using the shutdown button, twice after using the shutdown command. I’m not sure if it would cause problems, but it shouldn’t be left up to chance. You can put a logging feature in the script. Simply add `echo %date% %time% >> D:\test.txt` to the beginning of your script and that file will fill with the current date and time the script was last run. You can also use task scheduler for this. There is also a difference between log off and shutdown scripts. You need to know which one you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  The second shutdown line was put in to add a delay. I thought if i could see a 20 second delay on shutdown, at least i'd know the script was being looked at.  It wasn't and i've now removed this line but still doesn't work.  Have tried it as shutdown and logoff but neither worked.   Shutdown is what i want.  I'll try thr echo script

Comment: [don't put code in an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Tries the echo line but the file was not created which i guess confirms Windows isn't looking at the script.  Not sure what you mean Vinh about putting code in an image.  I did a screenshot for this post but it is a notepad file saved as a .bat on the PC

Comment: Oh i see what you mean about not putting code in an image.  Just realised it was a link and it's clear now. Sorry

Comment: Then look in event viewer for why the script didn’t run. Group policy failures will show up there.

Comment: Had a look but nothing to suggest a group policy failure. Any other suggestions please

Comment: Tried and tried and i now find that adding the line echo %date% %time% >> D:\test.txt to the script does produce the text file with time and date, however, still not shutting the program down.  Is it possible i need to add a time delay after the taskkill command?

Comment: See https://www.tenforums.com/customization/31729-windows-10-home-shutdown-script.html

Comment: Thanks  @DrMoishe.  Windows 10 wasn't looking at the batch file because i had 'fastboot' turned on in power options.  Turned it off and can now see the script being run on shutdown.  Folder Lock still doesn't close as it says process not found.  Thought it may have been the space in the name so tried various alternatives with quotes and wildcards. Still no good.  If i type taskkill folder* into the cmd prompt, it shuts down fine.  If i put a different process name into the script, that shuts down fine.  It appears to be this particular program.  Maybe  hides itself from the operating system.

Comment: Another possibility: run the encryption application from *within* another that checks for the WM_SHUTDOWN message... might require a bit of programming.